# Scrapy Getting Start_Urls

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

Ok, going to keep this short, need to rush off for a meeting

I am trying to get the start urls in scrapy and no matter how i try, i can't seem to accomplish it. Here is my code(spider).

```
import scrapy
import csv

from scrapycrawler.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request


class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["snipplr.com"]


def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(1, 230):
        yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.snipplr.com/view/%d" % i)




def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    item = DmozItem()

    # assign url
    item['link'] = url
    request = Request(url, dont_filter=True)

    # set the meta['item'] to use the item in the next call back
    request.meta['item'] = item
    return request


#Rules only apply before
rules = (
    Rule (LxmlLinkExtractor(deny_domains=('http:\/\/www.snipplr.com\/snippet-not-found\/',)),callback="parse", follow= True),
)


def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['title'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="post"]/h1/text()').extract()
    #start_url
    item['link'] = response.url
```

I have tried all ways, and till now, i get a "h" in my database, the url column.

[image: this]

This is my database :

```
import csv
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log
import sys
 import mysql.connector

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='ws', passwd='ps', db='ws')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT title,url FROM items WHERE title= %s", item['title'])
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:

            log.msg("Item already in database: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(
               "INSERT INTO items (title, url) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                    (item['title'][0], item['link'][0]))
            self.connection.commit()

            log.msg("Item stored : " % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        return item

    def handle_error(self, e):
            log.err(e)
```

As u can see from here, 
[image: here]
it is clearly working.

How would i get the start url or rather how would i prase it. I believe h means that the field is empty. Database is mysql.

Thanks for your reading and for your help

Regards,
Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item['link']`, as opposed to `item['title']`, is just a string, not a list:

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO items (title, url) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                    (item['title'][0], item['link']))
```

Comment: Oh ok, what difference does it make if there is a [0] or not do u mind me asking ? Thanks

Comment: @CharlieC `item['link'][0]` was taking the first character out of the string - which was `h`. Hope that makes sense.